# How to reduce the docker image size which is already committed

Tags: docker, image, image-resizing, image-size, docker-layer

I know that the docker image is read-only. Therefore, deleting the file inside base-image  within container does not change the size of docker. (result of `docker ps -s`)

I wanted to reduce image size, but it's already committed, and I can't reduce it. Because committed image is read-only.
How can I delete the files inside the image? Or is there a way to commit image read-and-write mode instead of read-only?

Comment: You need to modify the image's Dockerfile to not include the file (usually not delete it, but rather arrange for it to not exist at all) and then `docker build` the new image.  "Commit" should not be part of your Docker vocabulary.  Do you have a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: what is the issue with my answer?

Answer (score -1):

The way to achieve it is creating a new image without the file.

After you have deleted the file(s) you want to inside the running container, run:

> docker export <container id> -o <filename>

and

> docker import <filename> <image name>

Doing it you will get a new image without those files.

To delete the files:

> docker exec -ti <container id> /bin/bash

and delete the files

Comment: What is the issue?